# How to add Option Group to Event Online Registration?

Tags: civievent

I've made a new Option Group, but I'm struggling to add it to the Online Registration of an Event. How can I do this?

As an example, say I've created an Option Group to record a Participant's favourite colour for an Event. I can see that an Event's Online Registration includes a Profile. The Profile is made up of Fields. These Fields are made up of Options Groups. I can't seem to find how to associate Option Groups with Fields. I'd greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shaun, Welcome to CiviCRM SE,

You will need to

1. Add a custom group extending participant (CiviCRM >> Administer >> Customize Data and Screens >> Custom fields)
2. Add custom field of type select/radio/checkbox in a custom group created in #1.
3. Include this custom field in your profile which you are thinking to include for event.

Note: Custom field UI doesn't provide option to select existing option group which is not part of any custom field, you can either re-enter the options again or save the form without options and using api/sql update the option_group_id(with the option group id you have already created) column in civicrm_custom_field table for custom field you created at #2.

Thanks

Pradeep

Comment: Hi Pradeep, thank you very much for your help, I will try and remember to think Custom Fields and not Dropdown Options in the future!